# No inductor - any induced EMF when switch flipped on?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetic-fields, electric-circuits, inductance

My instructor put in the notes a picture of a loop without an inductor -
just a battery with voltage $\epsilon$, a switch, and resistor with resistance $R$. He explains that as soon as the switch is flipped, an emf is created that will oppose the change in flux. With an inductor, I can see how this would happen. But this made me wonder what happens when there isn't an inductor. Does current immediately reach $\epsilon\ /\ R$? Or is there some back emf that opposes flux change? It would make sense thinking about it that even without an inductor, there would be a resistance to flux change inside the closed loop, so it wouldn't immediately reach $I = \epsilon\ /\ R$.

Comment: A loop of wire **is** an inductor, it just doesn't usually have a particularly high inductance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is that there is always inductive coupling between the legs of such a loop.   Beyond that, [transmission line theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_line) answers your question of what happens.  Basically, there's parasitic inductance and capacitance everywhere you go, and they ensure you never see instantaneous jumps in current.

Comment: Thank you!! So does an inductor effectively just amplify this a ton by its solenoid shape?

Comment: Yes.  The shape of the inductor creates a stronger magnetic field than you'd get from stray wires (far stronger!).  In fact, it's so much stronger that in most calculations you can ignore any magnetic effects that don't involve a bunch of loops of wire.  Only at high frequencies and corner cases (like the one you mention) do we start having to pay attention to parasitic inductances.

Comment: Interestingly enough, this is one of the first lessons in the definitive book on high speed digital electronics: *The Art of High Speed Digital Design: a handbook of black magic*.  In it, they describe how a capacitor can start to look like an inductor at high frequencies because the capacitor's two metal legs start to create a noticeable inductive effect.  Trimming the capacitor legs actually changes the character of the circuit!

Comment: thank you Cort! Extremely informative! Would you be able to explain why the capacitor legs have a relatively large inductive effect?

Comment: The legs are two parallel wires, and parallel wires couple inductively.  It's not a lot of inductance, but at high frequencies (gigahertz), it doesn't take a lot of inductance to create a high impedence (resistance at a given frequency).  And by "corner cases" I meant unusual circumstances like "I actually care about whether its an instantaneous rise or fall, or just a really really really fast one."

Comment: Thank you! Super fascinating. I appreciate you taking the time to answer so thoroughly.